# C# How to get the sync folder of ActiveSync

Tags: c#, activesync

I'm not sure about my question so here it goes:
In C#, how do I get the location of the sync folder of ActiveSync/Windows Mobile Center?
so I could programatically read and write files into it.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do it using RAPI, have a look at the OpenNET CF here: http://rapi.codeplex.com/